# Visualization of ICA (Independent component analysis) results to the brain spatial regions

Tags: fmri, visualization

In [Calhoun et al, 2002](http://mialab.mrn.org/software/gift/publications/2002_HBM_Driving.pdf), on the application of ICA to fMRI on page 4, ICA data is mapped to the different regions in the brain.

**Brain Activation Maps**

[image]

**Question**

My specific question here is that when we have got results of ICA in the form of spatially Independent components, then how are those data mapped to the brain activation region?

Also using visualization How do we know that which component is task related that is there must be some default component for a particular activity. For example If a person is doing some activity like seeing a picture and his/her fMRI is being done then how based on ICA when we got say 30 component we would see that which component is related to that activity?

**My Understanding**

Those template brain regions have spatial locations like x,y coordinates so these ICA components would be somehow transformed to coordinate system.

<sub>Calhoun, V. D., Pekar, J. J., McGinty, V. B., Adali, T., Watson, T. D., & Pearlson, G. D. (2002). [Different activation dynamics in multiple neural systems during simulated driving.](http://mialab.mrn.org/software/gift/publications/2002_HBM_Driving.pdf) Human brain mapping, 16(3), 158-167.</sub>